# Confused about seeing vector values using gdb

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb

I have a function that reads an external value and stores in them in some variables. THe header file  is below:

```
struct surface {
    int NPoints;
    int NTriangles;
    vector <double> coor_x;
    vector <double> coor_y;
    vector <double> coor_z;
    vector <double> coor_nx;
    vector <double> coor_ny;
    vector <double> coor_nz;
    vector <int> indexa;
    vector <int> indexb;
    vector <vector <int> > v2t;
};

class Solve{
 public:
     ErrorCode loadRawn(char * fname, PBRawnAndQuadInfo * surf);

}
```

The function I'm problems with is below:

```
ErrorCode Solve::load(char * fname, Info * surface) {

  ifstream fin(fname);
  fin >> surface->NPoints >> surface->NTriangles;

  for (int i=0; i<surface->NPoints; i++) {
    double xx,yy,zz;
    fin >> xx >> yy >> zz;
    surface->coor_x.push_back(xx);
    fin >> xx >> yy >> zz;
    surface->coor_nx.push_back(xx);
  }

  surface->v2t.resize(surface->NPoints);

ofstream file;
file.open("output.txt");

  for (int i=0; i<surf->NTriangles; i++) {
    int a,b,c;
    fin >> a >> b >> c;
    surface->indexa.push_back(a);
    surface->indexb.push_back(b);
    surface->v2t[a].push_back(i);
    surface->v2t[b].push_back(i);
    file<<"indices: "<<surface->indexa[i]<<" "<<surface->indexb[i]<<endl;
    file<<"a: "<<a<<" b "<<b<<" c "<<c<<" i "<<i;
    file<<"v2t: "<<surface->vt2[ surface->indexa[i] ][i]<<" "<<surface->v2t[ surface->indexbi] ][i]<<endl;MolEnergy
  }
  file.close();
  return 0;
}
```

The actual values in the input file I use for `fname` in the `load` function are:

```
24 44
27.566549 3.457037 62.057549 -0.221094 -0.700101 -0.222706
27.566549 4.397549 61.117039 -0.221094 -0.221094 -0.701714
[get rows of 6 columns of values until 25th line]
...
0 2 1 //this is 26th line
0 3 4
1 3 0
0 2 1
0 3 4
1 3 0
3 5 4
1 6 7
2 6 1
3 1 8
1 7 8
8 5 3
9 5 8
7 6 10
7 11 8
10 11 7
8 11 9
13 2 0
12 2 13
4 14 0
14 13 0
15 4 5
14 4 15
2 12 6
6 12 16
5 9 15
9 17 15
10 16 18
6 16 10
11 10 19
19 10 18
9 19 17
11 19 9
13 20 12
14 20 13
21 20 14
15 21 14
12 22 16
20 22 12
21 23 20
20 23 22
17 21 15
23 21 17
16 22 18
23 18 22
19 18 23
17 19 23
```

`

Yet, when I use gdb to print out the values of `a` and `b` at the line `fin >> a >> b`, the initial values are 0 for a and 24 for b. At the line `surface->indexa[i].push_back(a)` when I print out `a` and `b`, the values are 0 and 10 respectively. It is not until the line `surf->vert2tris[a].push_back(i);` that the printed value for `a` and `b` are correct at 0 and 2, respectively. Is gdb supposed to do this?

What I am having even more trouble understanding is what goes on with the `v2t` variable. In the `output.txt` file, it shows the first couple values for `v2t` are `0 0`, `1 0`, and then `34667504 -738656440`. This is definitely wrong as the program should not be doing this. When I type 
`print surface->v2t`

I get the following long message
`$16 = { >, std::allocator > > >> = {
    _M_impl = { > >> = {<__gnu_cxx::new_allocator > >> = {}, }, _M_start = 0x1c53c70, _M_finish = 0x1c53eb0, 
      _M_end_of_storage = 0x1c53eb0}}, }

What is going on? How can I check what is causing the clearly incorrect values of v2t that are printed out in the `output.txt` file?

EDIT : I added the lines below to check for out-of-bounds issues, but these lines indicated out-of-bounds is not an issue since "skip" was never displayed in the output file

```
file<<"surface->v2t.size()"<<surface->v2t.size()<<endl;
if (a >= surface->v2t.size() || b >= surface->v2t.size() )
{file<<"skip:"<<endl;}
```

Comment: There's way too many unknowns when you only post a little piece of code. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for how to post code.

Comment: `surface->v2t[a].push_back(i); surface->v2t[b].push_back(i);`  The `a` and `b` in `vt2` know nothing about what the limits are of that vector.   I don't know if this is why gdb is showing you bad values, but the code itself looks faulty, or at the very least, potentially faulty.

Comment: any idea as to how I can fix this? I inherited this code from a previous coworker

Comment: @user4352158 Well, if `a >= v2t.size()` or `b >= v2t.size()`, then you have a problem.  You will have to know what the intent was of the code if the input values would result in an out-of-bounds access.

Comment: I just checked the code by adding the lines in the OP to check for out-of-bounds issues, but they were never hit, so that isn't the issue

Comment: Please indicate your version of GDB, your OS, and how you compile your program.

Comment: When you say "when I use gdb to print out the values of a and b at the line `fin >> a >> b`, the initial values are 0 for a and 24 for b", do you mean you set a breakpoint at that line and then typed `(gdb) print a` ? A breakpoint stops execution *before* a line is executed. At that line, the initial values of a and b are undefined.

Comment: We can better help you if we can see the entire contents of the input file.

Comment: the input file is quite large, though I added more details of it in the OP.

Comment: I am using Scientific Linux and (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux (7.2-75.el6). I compile the program using a `makefile` in a Build directory and then go to another directory and type `./run.sh singles.txt`. The command I use to run gdb is `gdb ../cmake/Project/Build/bin/Project` and then `run -PP Input/geometryname.inp`